Determine a positive constant $c$ such that the equation $xy^2 - y^2 - x + y = c$ has precisely three solutions $(x, y)$ in positive integers.
Determine a positive constant $c$ such that the equation
$xy^2 - y^2 - x + y = c$
has precisely three solutions $(x, y)$ in positive integers.
I've been struggling with the below question trying to use quadratic knowledge.

Please edit to include your efforts.  Just working a few examples for $C$  is a good start.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.
